Explanation of Linear Independence proof
Assume $v_1, .., v_n$ are nonzero and pairwise orthogonal, and suppose that $\alpha_1v_1 + \  .. \ + \ \alpha_nv_n = 0$
Then for each $j = 1, \ .., \ n$
$$
\begin{align}
0 & = \langle 0, v_j \rangle \\
& = \  \langle \alpha_1v_1 + \  .. \ + \ \alpha_n v_n, v_j \rangle \\
& = \alpha_1 \langle v_1, v_j \rangle + \ .. + \ \alpha_n \langle v_n, v_j \rangle \\
& = \alpha_j \langle v_j, v_j \rangle 
\end{align}
$$
since $v_j \neq 0, \langle v_j, v_j \rangle \ > 0$, so  $\alpha_j = 0$. Hence, $v_j,\ .., \ v_n$ are linearly independent.
What I am confused about here is that my understanding of linear independence is such that for some linear combination $\alpha_1v_1 + \  .. \ + \ \alpha_nv_n = 0$, then $\alpha_j = 0, \forall j$ but unless I am mistaken, the proof above only asserts that a specific $\alpha_j =0$ at any one time.
For example, if I were to say let $j = 1$ then because of the pairwise orthogonality of the vectors, then the inner product $\langle v_1, v_k \rangle = 0$ for $k = 2, \ .., \ n$. The coefficients $\alpha_k$ are then free to be any scalar which doesn't satisfy the condition of linear independence.
Am I missing something here or is this correct?

The proof says for each $j$. Which means $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ are all zeros.

Hi, sorry I do not think my fluency with proof writing is great. I do not follow entirely as the proof only takes a specific $v_j$ in the inner product at any given time, so cant the coefficients for the $k \neq j$ take any value since $\langle v_k, v_j \rangle = 0 $

$j$ is not a constant here, it is a variable. The proof shows how to prove that $\alpha_j=0$ for every $j$. If you want to show $\alpha_k=0$ then you take the inner product $\langle 0, v_k\rangle$, not the inner product with $v_j$. For example, $\alpha_1=0$ because $0=\langle 0, v_1\rangle=...$ (continue the proof), $\alpha_2$ is zero because $0=\langle 0, v_2\rangle=...$, and so on. So yes, you prove it separately for each $j$, but at the end you get all the coefficients are zeros.

Thank you very much for explaining this.
